# Can a function within a class's method access all the local variables within the method?

Tags: python, function, methods

```
def method(self, *args):
   def function(*args):
      #can this access all method's variables, data, etc.
```

Comment: In a word, yes. It would help if you explained a bit more of what you hoped to accomplish.

Comment: This is something that can easily be verified by a little first hand experimentation. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I get LocalUnboundErrors though when I tried it. So I was just checking if it was just me or if it actually can't be done.

Comment: Ok. Please post what you've tried. It would greatly facilitate figuring out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can,because python follows the following look-up rule while finding a variable:

**LEGB**:

```
L:local
E:enclosing
G:global
B:built-in
```

So, in your case it's `E`:

**python 2.x**:

in python 2.x you can't modify those variables in the func

```
class A:
    def meth(self):
        foo=1
        bar=2
        def func():
            foo=2     # if you place this statement below the print statement then you'll get
                      # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment
            print foo,bar
        func()    
        print (foo) #meth's foo is unchanged
a=A()
a.meth()
```

**output:**

```
2 2 
1
```

python 3.x:
   use `nonlocal` to even modify the variables:

```
class A:
    def meth(self):
        foo=1
        bar=2
        def func():
            nonlocal foo,bar             
            print (foo,bar)
            foo=2               #changes meth's foo to 2
        func()    
        print (foo)
a=A()
a.meth()
```

**output:**

```
1 2
2
```